# Condition checking on NSMutableDictionary

Tags: swift, nsmutabledictionary

I have NSMutableDictionary with (key,value) pairs.For JournalId the key is "journalId".I just want to check whether my dictionary contains specific "journalId", for eg, 29. If it exists, need to print the corresponding title and userId.
eg.

```
{
    journalId = 28;
    title = Creed;
    userId = 105; } {
    journalId = 29;
    title = Fg;
    userId = 105; } {
    journalId = 30;
    title = Dhh;
    userId = 105; }
```

I want to check in my dictionary whether it has journalId value = 28.

```
if (dictValues["journalId"] == 28){
print(dictValues["title"]
}
```

The above method shows error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please provide complete information.

Comment: Are you having array of Dictionary?

Comment: What you have is not even data with NSMutableDictionary.  It's raw data before converted into JSON.  Why do you even want to use NSMutableDictionary in Swift?  Why not using Dictionary instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
guard dictValues["journalId"] as! Int == 28 else {
    print("key Not found")
    return // exit the function
}
let title = dictValues["title"] as! String
print("\(title)")
```

Comment: This solution is in swift 3. Executed in Playground Xcode 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let journalId = dictValues["journalId"] as? Int, journalId == 28 {
  print(dictValues["title"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` subsctiption returns an object of type `AnyObject?`.
This code should resolve your problem

```
if (dictValues["journalId"] as? Int == 28) {
   print(dictValues["title"])
}
```